# Is the utility of eval() worth what it costs in performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, eval

It's my understanding that using eval can cause browser performance optimizations to be skipped.  However, executing programmatically generated code seems like it could be incredibly useful.  Are there cases where the benefits of *eval* outweigh the costs?

Comment: Much too broad a question (and/or opinion based) for SO's format, I'm afraid. You'll get the "`eval` is always evil" brigade, and the "`eval` is fine if you know what's up" brigade, and ne'er the twain shall meet. :-) (FWIW: It's been *years* since I last found myself in a situation where I thought `eval` was necessary, and that situation is no longer relevant on modern browsers.)

Comment: JavaScript is already environment-aware, you can execute code based on the environment. Generating code seems useful only to optimize something (development time or execution time), so I guess you generaly will generate the code **before** running it. My tip is that `eval` is not useful in this sense, there are better ways to do what you are trying with `eval`.

Comment: "*eval can cause browser performance optimizations to be skipped... executing programmatically generated code seems... incredibly useful*" -- you're identified a trade-off between the utility of the `eval` feature and its negative performance impact. If your requirements value the feature's utility more than they are intolerant of the performance impact, then you should use `eval` to satisfy your requirements. I suppose you're asking if any such requirements would ever be sensible, which I think might be too broad of a question for Stack Overflow.